# How to hide few default fields for specific user

Tags: users

I want to hide fields such as password, email when a particular user tries to edit few fields of other users.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi for this there is many possible way to achieve this you can use 
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions/releases/7.x-1.0-beta2
(The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.)
or by custom module

```
 function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id === 'you_form_id') {

  if (in_array('user_role_type', $user->roles)){
    //do stuff

     // Use var_dump  to dump the $form array to see the fields. 
     // var_dump ($form);

     unset($form['mail']);
     unset($form['pass']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried with field permission and user protector modules and while editing other user automatically i could see this email and password field of other user.

Comment: another way is by form alter  like$items['foo/bar/user'] = array(
    'title' => 'Foobar',
    'description' => 'List, add, and edit Foobars.',
    'page callback' => 'foo_bar_function',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
  );

Comment: sorry i am not getting because i have no idea how to do this form alter n where exactly what to do, if u  can tell me or explain it would be great helpful

Comment: check above code just replace authenticated user to your user access to hide fields

Comment: this piece of code where to paste or modify is it in user.module?sorry if i am being dumb

Comment: make folder  in module directory name it  mymodule under this make two files (1)mymodule.info (2) mymodule.module put  above code on it  follow this https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41436/discussion-between-naveen-and-neethu).

Comment: This code is completely wrong, since: it would remove the mail and password fields for every user, and you don't `unset()` form fields. The form ID is also completely wrong.